# define a type in an object literal

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to define a type directly in an object litteral ?

```
const myObj = {
   brand:'foo',
   reset() {
      this.brand = undefined // Won't work since brand is inferred as a string.
                             // I would like to type brand as 'string | undefined'. 
                             // Can I do this directly in the object literal without
                             // creating and Interface?
   }
}
```

Comment: `const myObj: { brand?: string, reset: () => void } = {`

Comment: or `const myObj = { brand:'foo' as string | undefined, ... }`

Comment: `'foo' as string | undefined` looks like cheating, you're trying to convince a compiler `'foo'` string literal can be `undefined`

Comment: @zerkms type assertions have their own assignment compatibility checks - you wouldn't be able to write `brand:'foo' as number | undefined`. In this case there is no loss of type checking.

Comment: @ford04 I know that, I just mentioned it looks like a cheat (because you're telling a value can be `undefined`). And yep - in this case there is no, but there are cases when using `as` breaks type-safety.

Comment: @zerkms I totally agree with you that the explicit type is the better way to do it. `as` is just a quick and dirty way that fulfills the job here. But you are probably confusing more than you do good, especially if others/co-workers are not aware of how it works.